# Finding meeting points of Digital Rivers

Tags: python, algorithm

I was given the following problem:

> A digital river is a sequence of numbers where every number is followed by the same number plus the sum of its digits. In such a sequence 123 is followed by 129 (since 1 + 2 + 3 = 6), which again is followed by 141.
>
> We call a digital river river *K*, if it starts with the value *K*.
> For example:
> river 7 is the sequence beginning with {7, 14, 19, 29, 40, 44, 52, ... } and
> river 471 is the sequence beginning with {471, 483, 498, 519, ... }.
>
> Digital rivers can meet. This happens when two digital rivers share the same values. River 32 meets river 47 at 47, while river 471 meets river 480 at 519.
>
> Given two meeting digital rivers, print out the meeting point.

To solve this problem, I wrote this code (`r_1` and `r_2` are the starting points of the rivers) :

```
r_1 = [int(input())]
r_2 = [int(input())]

while True:
    r_1.append(r_1[-1] +  sum([int(d) for d in str(r_1[-1])]))
    r_2.append(r_2[-1] +  sum([int(d) for d in str(r_2[-1])]))
    if r_2[-1] in r_1:
        print(r_2[-1]),
        break
    elif r_1[-1] in r_2:
        print(r_1[-1])
        break
```

This code works, but when `r_1` or `r_2` are big, and the meetings points are far away in the rivers, the computing time is too long. I used a single `while` loop, and two `if` statements, so I can't see how can I improve this code.

How can I make it less time consuming?

Comment: Might be a better question for [codereview.se]

Comment: You did not share maximum input range for rivers.

Comment: an improvement might be to generate each new number in the sequence with the last smallest number, and check if it less, equal or greater than the last number in the other sequence. If its less, you calculate another number, if it's equal you end the program, if it's greater you do the same thing but switching the sequences. This way you calculate new numbers only if needed. Hope I've explained it well enough. If you have any questions, you're free to ask me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear that a digital river is an ever increasing series, it never decreases. So to find the point where two join, you only need to keep track of the current value of both rivers, and only update the one that has the least value. If it overtakes the other, then advance the other...etc, until you get the *same* value.

Again, you just need to keep the updated value that way. There is no reason to build a list.

Example:

```
a = 471
b = 480

while a != b:
    if a < b:
        a += sum([int(d) for d in str(a)])
    else:
        b += sum([int(d) for d in str(b)])

print(a) # 519
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding new items to both lists regardless of how far apart they are. Try only calculating the next step in the river which has a *lower* value, rather than both of them, which could result in extra calculations that are not required.

```
while True:
    # if its found, break
    if r_1[-1] == r_2[-1]:
        print(r_1[-1])
        break
    else:
        # if r_1 is larger, only increment r_2
        if r_1[-1] > r_2[-1]:
            r_2.append(r_2[-1] + sum([int(d) for d in str(r_2[-1])]))
        # if r_2 is larger, only increment r_1
        elif r_1[-1] < r_2[-1]:
            r_1.append(r_1[-1] + sum([int(d) for d in str(r_1[-1])]))
```

Note: This also does not specify an upper bound, so might run forever if the rivers are not ever going to match.

Comment: The easiest solution to the bound I see at first glance, is to hold the distance between the values of the river. For example you can see if river 10 is behind river 11 by 2 points, if that number increases then you know that the river 11 is going faster than river 10 so you can stop when that numbers starts increasing.

Comment: This implies the rivers move as fast as each other, but they do not, since this problem is based on digits and not just values. Using r_1=13 and r_2=14, the distance between the two rivers varies between 1 and 15, until the final answer is found when the lists are of length 50 and 53 respectively.

Comment: Well the speed at which the rivers are moving are defined by you. The first valued will be 10, the next will be 11, the next will be 13 for the river10. For river11 it will be 11, then 13, then 17. The rivers will never meet if they continue _flowing_. However we can find out if one river is part of the other or the same, by trying out the answer @trincot gave. If the rivers meet and then continue having the same values then they are the same river, just one starting point was behind the other.

Comment: Fundamentally, the answer @trincot gave is the same as mine, albeit more efficient and condensed. Basing your bound on an increasing distance will not work, and the sample (a = 471, b = 480) shows this. The distance between a and b at each step is (9,3,9,6,9,12,0). With your idea, would that not mean when the distance goes from (3->9) or (6->9->12) that the bound would assume they would never meet (since the distance between is increasing) and end the algorithm prematurely?